# xforms:help not working in Orbeon 4.5

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I am trying to upgrade the version of orbeon from 3.9 to 4.5.
When i tried to run the same form which i created using Orbeon 3.9 in Orbeon 4.5,I am gettin 'Object Required' error when Help icon is clicked.

Thanks in Advance....

Answer (score 0):

I think it's this bug of orbeon 4.5 : http://discuss.orbeon.com/how-to-use-the-new-xforms-help-in-4-5-tp4658348p4658349.html

Julien

Comment: Thanks for your reply....So is there any option to be used instead of xforms:help?

Comment: The solution is to use Orbeon Forms 4.5.1 or 4.6.1 (the latest).

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in Orbeon Forms 4.5.1 PE. Use that, or the newly released Orbeon Forms 4.6.